# Socket.io - Optimizing communications between 2 sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm working with Nodejs, Express, and Socket.io, I started out with this tutorial for a chat with multiple rooms and which is quite popular:

http://psitsmike.com/2011/10/node-js-and-socket-io-multiroom-chat-tutorial/

I added a feature in which one player can challenge another one(within the room, where there might be other players) to a 1v1 rock, paper, scissor match in a turn based manner. Everytime a player chooses any of his 3 options available(rock,paper,scissor), I send to a function in the backend the ID of his opponent and the option chosen.

I wanna know if there is a better way to communicate through sockets other than sending the id each time, and what other alternatives are out there to emulate a match between 2 players only, without having to worry about the connection being lost or having other players interfere.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  socket.io is used for sending messages between client and server.  Sending the ID of an opponent and an option chosen sounds perfectly reasonable.  What kind of an answer were you expecting?  Or why did you think you needed to ask about this at all?  I'm confused.

Comment: For example, if i get the id of a player before he starts a match with someone else, I might be able to interfere in the connection between both

Comment: It's up to your server to make sure all communication between clients is legal and to prevent any undesired interference.  The server has to enforce the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you start a new room for a new game? Both challenger and opponent get added to the new room.

There will be no interference even if either player starts games with other opponents as all games are in separate rooms...